# Get list of existing child device of IoT edge device

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub

I am using preview version (v1.27.0-preview-003) of [Azure IoT SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Devices/1.27.0-preview-003). It supports establishing parent child relationship between IoT edge and IoT leaf device. The device object has `Scope` property. If `Scope` value of edge device is assigned to leaf device, it becomes the child of edge device. [Here's](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/commit/2705938c873ad2227274dfba480f13883bf46adb#diff-cb71fc4e5cefd60da214e8c25585b701) the test case for that.

```
RegistryManager registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString);

var edgeDevice = new Device(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
{
    Capabilities = new DeviceCapabilities
    {
        IotEdge = true
    }
};
edgeDevice = await registryManager.AddDeviceAsync(edgeDevice).ConfigureAwait(false);

var leafDevice = new Device(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
{
    Scope = edgeDevice.Scope
};

Device receivedDevice = await registryManager.AddDeviceAsync(leafDevice).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I want to fetch the child devices of any edge device, how can I do that? I can't find any method to retrieve the list of child device. Actually I want to modify the list of children of edge device. For leaf device, it's simple, there will be one parent so it's dead simple to replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this programmatically, You'll have to use a query on device registry with edge device's `deviceScope`.

It is available in the az iot extension directly:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-cli-iot-ext/iot/hub/device-identity?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-cli-iot-ext-az-iot-hub-device-identity-list-children

Comment: BTW, when I query using `deviceScope`, I also get the edge device so I need to put extra condition for `capabilities.iotEdge = false`.